# Whiptail --infobox in Debian does not work

Tags: whiptail

Someone working this code in Debian ?

```
whiptail --infobox "test" 0 0
```

Can you please try? My code does not work :-( How to fix the solution?

```
whiptail --msgbox "test" 0 0 # works fine
```

Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

I answered this in [Whiptail or dialog don't working by ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21042525/whiptail-or-dialog-dont-working-by-ssh).  The basic problem is that the infobox displays in xterm's alternate screen.  The dialog problem compensates for this; whiptail does not.