# Whiptail or dialog don't working by ssh

Tags: bash, ssh, dialog, whiptail

I have Ubuntu 12.04 Server at virtual machine and installed OpenSSH server on it. I have simple script with whiptail

```
#!/bin/sh
whiptail --title "Example dialog" --infobox "TTTTTT" 8 78
```

On server this script is working and i seen the infobox. But in SSH session i have no output.

```
user@ubuntu:~$ ./script
user@ubuntu:~$ ./script
user@ubuntu:~$
```

Bash script using dialog doesn't working on server.

How i can create visual menu script working in SSH session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

whiptail seems to be buggy displaying infoboxes on certain terminals (see [How to display infobox in whiptail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13000391/how-to-display-infobox-in-whiptail)). Maybe you can try a --msgbox instead to verify your script works

```
whiptail --title "I am the title" --msgbox "Hi there" 8 45
```

Answer (score 0):

Running `whiptail --infobox` in xterm can do this, which results in no visible display:

- suppose that xterm's terminal description includes the alternate-screen switching (which most do, since that is the way xterm and ncurses define it): `smcup=\E[?1049h, rmcup=\E[?1049l,`
- alternate-screen switching is enabled.
- conventional terminal applications send `smcup` at the beginning
- whiptail is conventional...
- it displays the `--infobox` in the alternate screen
- there's nothing more to do (no buttons to click), so whiptail exits
- on the way out, it sends `rmcup`, switching back to the normal screen
- the output from the `--infobox` is lost

This matches the behavior reported in OP's question.  The [Red Hat](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=91596) report mentioned in *[How to display infobox in whiptail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13000391/how-to-display-infobox-in-whiptail)* is describing the same problem, as well as the one in [Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/newt/+bug/604212).

The problem was first addressed in dialog in [2003](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/CHANGES.html#t20030130) (though there have been occasional maintenance fixes since then).

The solution used in the other questions was to use [dialog](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/dialog.html) (the actual program, rather than the generic "dialog" mentioned in OP's question).